# How to adjust alt+g?

Tags: modeling, shortcut

I am watching a tutorial where alt+g is used to move a cube to the center and it looks like this.[image: chair]

But, when I do it alt+g results in this[image: my chair]

I also want my object to move onto the center. How can I do that please?

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't have your object origin aligned correctly.
Set your object origin to the middle of the bottom of your 4 chair legs, then pressing alt g sould do the trick.

Comment: The object origin should be that orange point, but it´s missing. Where can I turn that on? "Set your object origin to the middle of the bottom of your 4 chair legs"you mean by selecting the chair legs and using set origin> origin to center of mass(volume)? That doesn´t work.

Comment: You need the object to be selected (yellow outline) before ALT-G will have any effect. The origin point should also appear when it is selected.

Comment: It's the cube, not the chair that he's moving.  The cube's origin should be at the center of the bottom face.

Comment: The problem never was to make alt+g work but how. The origin points in my file are still missing/ not displayed. Can´t tell how that happened.

Comment: Go to overlays-> display origins

Comment: Yes, that´s it. Could have thought of that myself.